# How to decay rvalues reference type whilst preserving lvalue references in C++14?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, boost-optional

I have the following C++14 lambda

https://godbolt.org/z/aexxTY

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>


int main(){
    auto foo = [](auto && t) 
    {
        using T = decltype(t);
        return boost::optional<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
    };

    // This is fine because i is lvalue
    auto i = 10;
    foo(i);

    // This fails because i is rvalue
    foo(10);
}
```

First note that boost::optional can contain lvalue references but not rvalue references.

Is it possible with the above generic lambda to handle the rvalue as a copy. What I'd like is something clever like

```
using T = std::decay_if_rvalue<decltype(t)>::type
```

Is there something out of the box that does this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::is_rvalue_reference` together with `std::conditional`, both from the `<type_traits>` header.

```
auto foo = [](auto && t) 
{
    using Orig = decltype(t);
    using T = std::conditional_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<Orig>::value,
            std::decay_t<Orig>, Orig>;
    return boost::optional<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WdTdco

Comment: Thankyou. I edited the answer so that it was c++ 14 compliant and added a link to godbolt with the compiling example.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a type trait as

```
template< class T > struct remove_rvalue_reference       {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_rvalue_reference <T&&> {typedef T type;};
```

then

```
using T = typename remove_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::type;
```

then

```
auto i = 10;
foo(i);   // T will be int& in the lambda

foo(10);  // T will be int  in the lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [lubgr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66114278) you can encapsulate the conditional type in an alias compatible with C++14 like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
using decay_rvalue_reference_t = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value,
    std::decay_t<T>::type,
    T>;

auto foo = [](auto && t) 
{
    using T = decay_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(t)>;
    return boost::optional<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YW88Yf

Comment: In my production code this is exactly what I did. A nice addition to the answers!

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I originally thought my answer was more useful until I realized the `_t` variants were in fact available in C++14 `<type_traits>` header. Now I think my answer is only marginally useful :P (I managed to get the edit in before the 5 minute window so you can't see my original answer)

Comment: I still think it is a good idea to factor things like this out because when reading the code later on you see the concept ``decay_rvalue_reference_t`` named rather than the implementation. It's a small thing but it's worth it.